# Could not load System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, razor, oauth

I added Facebook autentization to my asp.net web forms application. I am using *Microsoft WebPages OAuth library* and I used NuGet packages to add it to the project.

But when I started debuging, error page displayed:

> could not load file or setting  System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35...
>   system could not find the file.

Link to printscreen of error page - [http://sdrv.ms/1gE3L8m](http://sdrv.ms/1gE3L8m.) (it's in czech language, but I hope it will help).

I tried to add reference to *Web.WebPages.Razor* to *packages.config* file, but it didn't help.

Coudl you please help me solving this issue? I can add the code of my Facebook autentication if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens due to using the wrong version of the plugin. Its updated your references (its a total pain). The best way is to remove the package and then use the correct version - there is  probably one for mvc 3 instead of the one for mvc 4 which was installed.

Comment: Just for sure, which package should I remove and install other version - Microsoft ASP.NET Razor or Microsoft WebPages OAuth library?

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I'm having the same issue.